# Global variable in Column Transformer scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

in this snippet I built a transformer that insert one column, but it seems to modify the original variable. In fact I cannot repeat the fit operation. Is this expected? This breaks the behavior of grid_search for example because it tries to insert the column for every grid fit.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin
class customColumnTransformer(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        return self
    
    def transform(self,X):
        X.insert(0,'newCol',1)
        return X
    
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])
display(customColumnTransformer().fit_transform(df))
display(df)
# display(customColumnTransformer().fit_transform(df))   THIS GENERATE AN ERROR  ValueError: cannot insert newCol, already exists
```

The only solution I found is to use
customColumnTransformer().fit_transform(df.copy())

Answer (score 1):

Certainly! It's completely expected behavior. When you use the insert method to modify the DataFrame X within your transform function, it modifies the DataFrame in-place. Consequently, subsequent calls to fit_transform using the same DataFrame will result in an error since the column 'newCol' already exists.

To circumvent this issue and avoid modifying the original DataFrame, you can create a copy of it before inserting the new column. This way, each call to fit_transform will operate on a separate copy, leaving the original DataFrame intact.

Here's an updated version of your code that incorporates this change:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import pandas as pd

class CustomColumnTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        X_copy = X.copy()  # Create a copy of the DataFrame
        X_copy.insert(0, 'newCol', 1)
        return X_copy

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
display(CustomColumnTransformer().fit_transform(df))
display(df)
```

By utilizing X_copy = X.copy(), you generate a new DataFrame object X_copy that can be modified independently without affecting the original df DataFrame. Consequently, you can reuse the transformer multiple times without encountering the "already exists" error.

This revised code allows you to call fit_transform repeatedly on the same DataFrame without generating any errors.